# Moq mocking EF DbContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a Repository pattern that interacts with Entity Framework.
I'd like to run some unit tests on the repository, and for this reason, I would like to mock DbContext.

So I've created a unit test project (.Net Core 3.1), using Moq as package for unit testing, everything seems to be ok, but when I perform a .ToListAsync() on my repository it throws the following exception:

> System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not
> implemented.   Stack Trace: 
> IAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator() EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The source code:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomersDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public CustomersDbContext(DbContextOptions<Customer> options) : base(options) { }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomersAsync(Guid? customerId);
}
public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{

    private readonly CustomersDbContext _dbContext;

    public CustomerRepository(CustomersDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;

        _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomersAsync(Guid? customerId)
    {
        IEnumerable<Customer> customers = null;

        if (customerId.HasValue)
        {
            var customer = await _dbContext.Customers.FindAsync(new object[] { customerId.Value }, CancellationToken.None);

            if (customer != null)
                customers = new List<Customer>() { customer };
        }
        else
        {
            customers = await _dbContext.Customers.ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }

        return customers;
    }
}


public class CustomerServiceUnitTests
{
    private Mock<CustomersDbContext> GetCustomerDbContextMock()
    {
        var data = new List<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Name 1"
            },
            new Customer()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Name 2"
            }
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Customer>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Customer>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Customer>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Customer>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Customer>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptions<CustomersDbContext>();

        var mockContext = new Mock<CustomersDbContext>(optionsBuilder);

        Mock<DatabaseFacade> databaseFacade = new Mock<DatabaseFacade>(mockContext.Object);
        databaseFacade.Setup(d => d.EnsureCreatedAsync(CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Database).Returns(databaseFacade.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Customers).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        return mockContext;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Infrastructure_CustomerRepository_GetAll()
    {

        var mockContext = this.GetCustomerDbContextMock();

        ICustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(mockContext.Object);

        var customers = await customerRepository.GetCustomersAsync(null);

        Assert.NotNull(customers);
        Assert.Equal(2, customers.Count());
    }
}
```

If I send an ID filled to the repository it works fine, so this seems to be not ok only for .ToListAsync().

I'm kinda stuck here, what can I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot mock `DbSet` query functionality. This is explained [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy#different-types-of-test-doubles):

> Properly mocking `DbSet` *query* functionality is not possible, since queries are expressed via LINQ operators, which are static
> extension method calls over `IQueryable`. As a result, when some
> people talk about "mocking `DbSet`", what they really mean is that they
> create a `DbSet` backed by an in-memory collection, and then evaluate
> query operators against that collection in memory, just like a simple
> `IEnumerable`. Rather than a mock, this is actually a sort of fake,
> where the in-memory collection replaces the the real database.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I ended up seting up an in-memory DbContext and worked like a charm. Mocking was actually unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute Asynchronous read operation (ToListAsync()) you need to mock an additional interface called "IDBAsyncQueryProvider".

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN#testing-with-async-queries) is the required link you can follow. It is under the heading "Testing with async queries"

Comment: lmk if you are able to figure it out :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. It seems to be a good approach, but I ended up following previous suggestion of using an in-memory DbContext, so I marked it as answered

Comment: ohk since you are choosing that path, I would like to suggest Entity framework effort, that is just the best package out there IMO. You can try that.